# Does Expresso Store 2.5.1 work with PHP7?

Tags: expresso-store, php7

I see another question like this was asked but really no answer was given for the 2.5.1 version.  Will it work with PHP 7?  I know there is a new Store 3 version, but I can't upgrade to EE3 due to several other missing add-ons for v3 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm with Vector; we own Expresso Store)

Official support for PHP 7 in Store was launched with Expresso Store 3. Store 2 could probably work with PHP 7 but that might require some changes to its code and isn't something we're planning on checking for. You can make those changes yourself, or [commissions us to do it](https://www.devdemon.com/contact/) if it's critical for you and you're unable to upgrade ExpressionEngine for other reasons!